# How can i make custom cursor in C#

Tags: c#, image, resources, cursor

Please, can you help with my errors for custom cursor?

**My scripts in form designer:**

```
this.Cursor = new System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(global::testCursor.Properties.Resources.test);
```

**Compilation error:**

```
Error   4   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'System.IntPtr'  G:\Programování\Projects\C#\testCursor\testCursor\Login.Designer.cs 255 59  testCursor
Error   3   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Cursor(System.IntPtr)' has some invalid arguments G:\Programování\Projects\C#\testCursor\testCursor\Login.Designer.cs 255 27  testCursor
```

I really thx for answers which can help me.

Comment: Did you already check out the [MSDN example for the System.Windows.Forms.Cursor constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? The error you get should be clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cursor API requires an `IntPtr` to the image but you are providing `Bitmap` value.  Use the `GetHbitmap` function to get the `IntPtr` value

```
Bitmap bitmap = global::testCursor.Properties.Resources.test;
this.Cursor = new System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(bitmap.GetHbitmap());
```

Comment: its looks nice but this line: Bitmap bitmap is not supported in form.designer.cs

Errors:

Comment: @RadekTarant the error message you already posted suggested you have a bitmap in `Resources.test`.  What do you actually have there?